# Ejs template file append in div using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have 2 ejs files. I need to append the template based on the label click.

Here i added index.ejs template code

```
<!--- Header content----->
<div class="btn-group filter-suggestions" data-toggle="buttons" style="margin-left:25px;">
    <label class="btn btn-default active" data-tab="tab1">
        <input type="radio"  name="suggest" value="1" />
        Tab1 </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default" data-tab="tab2">
        <input type="radio"  name="suggest" value="2" />
        Tab2 </label>
</div>
<div class="tabcontent"> TabContent</div>
<!-----------Content--------->
<!-----------Footer--------->
```

Here i added tab1.ejs template code

```
<div> Tab1 content</div>
```

Here i added tab2.ejs template code

```
<div> Tab2 content </div>
```

Here i add the js code for label click event.

```
$('.filter-suggestions label').on('click', function() {
//get the tab attribute type
var type = $(this).attr(tab);
if(type == tab1){
 var templatename = '/templates/Tab1.ejs'
} else {
 var templatename = '/templates/Tab1.ejs'
}
//here i replace the content based on the label
$ ('. tabcontent'). html (templatename);

});
```

Its not working. Have any idea to append the ejs template using node js?

Comment: Include them in your index and show/hide with js.

Answer (score 0):

EJS doesn't parse this way. The way your code is currently you are setting `templatename` to a string value of either `'/templates/Tab1.ejs'` or `'/templates/Tab2.ejs'` - it isn't going to read in the content of the .ejs files you have specified.

The easier way to approach this would be to load both tabs and have one or both of them hidden by default, then show the one you want based on the label click.

Here is some alternative code to try:

```
// Hide the tabs
$('#idoftab1, #idoftab2).hide();

$('.filter-suggestions label').on('click', function() {
    //get the tab attribute type
    var type = $(this).attr(tab);

    if(type == tab1){
        $('#idoftab1').show();
    } else {
       $('#idoftab2').show();
    }
});
```

If you are looking for a more programmatic way to achieve this via client side templates then you could look at using AngularJS or even libraries like [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/), but really that change might be overkill for what you want to achieve.